# How to detect font scaling mode used?

Tags: windows, scaling, dpi

In the Windows 7 "Custom DPI Setting" window, there is a setting called "Use Windows XP style DPI scaling". Does anyone know how to detect if this setting is in use?

Comment: Using what platform / technology?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if either of these will give you what you want but might be useful:

[IsProcessDPIAware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969261%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) - *Determines whether the current process is dots per inch (dpi) aware such that it adjusts the sizes of UI elements to compensate for the dpi setting.*

[Writing High-DPI Win32 Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd464660%28VS.85%29.aspx#getting_system_information) - Using the code in the *Getting System Information* section you could probably tell the difference in some way when the setting is on vs off.