# Programmatically detect the value of "Use Windows XP style DPI scaling"

Tags: c#

Is there a reliable way to find the value of "Use Windows XP style DPI scaling" checkbox value in Windows Vista and Windows 7? I found a way to get this value here:

http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/whatforum/thread/282a63c2-bd57-4639-811b-c03c6b82b49b/

However the registry key does not exist for Windows Vista.

My application is written in C# WPF. It needs to scale itself with respect to another application which is DPIAware. I need this value to decide in my application if I need to scale with DPI scaling. I don't want to apply dpi scale factor if the Windows XP style DPI scaling is on.

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595730/how-to-detect-font-scaling-mode-used/3595818#3595818

Comment: Declare your app dpi-aware in the manifest so the setting doesn't affect you at all.

Comment: What you really want to know is if the other process is DPI aware.  The Windows XP style DP scaling setting is only one factor.  See the question Davide Piras linked to in these comments.